# How to connect music system speakers to computer?

Tags: music, stereo

I have an old stereo system lying around, I am thinking of connecting it to my computer/television. However the main unit of the system is no longer working. How can I use the stereo speakers with my computer/television ? I am guessing that an amplifier will be needed, if so then should I be going for one that supports 2000 watts?

Model No: Panasonic SA-AK-133

I am unable to find an user manual .

[image: http://snag.gy/vY0no.jpg]

[image]

Comment: 2000 watts is a big marketing Lie. I doubt that system was 20 watts output.

Comment: Should I move this post to somewhere else ?